# How can I use data defined in data() in other methods in Vue js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-props

First I defined Types, Severities, and Statuses as [] and returned them in data().
Then I filled them with data in the methods getTypes(), getSeverities(), and getStatuses().
I want to use Types, Severities, and Statuses in the method getName()(just has console.log() as an example for now).
I noticed when debugging getNames(), type in the second for loop is undefined. Is it because the method is using Type before it was assigned values in getTypes()? How can I make it work?

Note: Types, Severities, and Statuses do get assigned values in the methods getTypes(), getSeverities(), and getStatuses(), the issues is how to use the data in other methods.

```
<script>
import IssuesTable from '../MyIssuesPage/IssuesTable.vue'
import AddIssue from '../MyIssuesPage/AddIssue.vue'
import axios from 'axios'

export default {
  props: ['id', 'project', 'issuesList', 'index'],
  components: { IssuesTable, AddIssue },
  data() {
    return {
      Issues: this.issuesList[this.index],
      tab: null,
      items: [{ tab: 'Issues' }, { tab: 'Calender' }, { tab: 'About' }],
      Types: [],
      Severities: [],
      Statuses: [],
    }
  },

  setup() {
    return {
      headers: [
        { text: 'Title', value: 'title' },
        { text: 'Description', value: 'description' },
        { text: 'Estimate', value: 'time_estimate' },
        { text: 'Assignees', value: 'userid' },
        { text: 'Type', value: 'issueTypeId' },
        { text: 'Status', value: 'issueStatusId' },
        { text: 'Severity', value: 'issueSeverityId' },
      ],
    }
  },

  mounted() {
    this.getTypes(), this.getSeverities(), this.getStatuses(), this.getNames()
  },

  methods: {
    getTypes() {
      axios
        .get('http://fadiserver.herokuapp.com/api/v1/my-types')
        .then(response => {
          this.Types = response.data
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.log(error)
        })
    },
    getSeverities() {
      axios
        .get('http://fadiserver.herokuapp.com/api/v1/my-severities')
        .then(response => {
          this.Severities = response.data
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.log(error)
        })
    },

    getStatuses() {
      axios
        .get('http://fadiserver.herokuapp.com/api/v1/my-status')
        .then(response => {
          this.Statuses = response.data
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.log(error)
        })
    },

    getNames() {
      for (var issue of this.Issues) {
        for (var type of this.Types) {
          if (issue.issueTypeId == type.id) console.log('test')
        }
      }
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, use created() instead of mounted() for calling methods that fetch data.

Next, you need to call getNames() only after all fetch methods complete.

```
created() {
this.getTypes()
  .then(this.getSeverities())
  .then(this.getStatuses())
  .then(this.getNames());
}
```

In order to chain methods like this you need to put return statement before each `axios` like this

```
  getTypes() {
  return axios
    .get("https://fadiserver.herokuapp.com/api/v1/my-types")
    .then((response) => {
      this.Types = response.data;
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
}
```

In this component, I see you are receiving `issuesList` and `index` props from the outside. I cannot know those values but you can console.log both of them inside created() and see what is happening because `issuesList[index]` is `undefined`.

That probably means `issuesList` is an array and that `index` does not exist in that array.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. console.log(this.issueList[this.index]) does output to the console the correct data to the console, meaning that both are defined. However, I still can not use Types, Severities, and Statuses in getNames(), even after I did what you suggested by using created() instead of mounted().

Comment: Try to attach your code into sandbox online and I can take a look